# SQL Jet Access, Insert Column and Order by

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet

I use `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` connection via excel to do an internal query within my workbook.

How can I insert a column `Year` with the years I have in my query and order them so they are not together. So they will repeat one after the other?

The `Year` Column added I have, but now ordering is the issue.

Here is my current query

```
select [Data Type], [Currency], [Book Name], [1987] as Value
from [stage2$]
UNION ALL
select [Data Type], [Currency], [Book Name], [1990]
from [stage2$]
```

Current Data:

```
+--------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------+
|           Data Type            | Currency | Name  |   value       |
+--------------------------------+----------+-------+--------------
| Missing Non Historical Results | BSD      | Carib | (279)         |
| Missing Non Historical Results | BSD      | Carib |   18          |
| Missing Non Historical Results | BSD      | Carib |   898         |
| Missing Non Historical Results | BSD      | Carib |  (50)         |
+--------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------+
```

Expected result:

```
+--------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+
|           Data Type            | Currency | Name  | Year          |  value  |
+--------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+
| Missing Non Historical Results | BSD      | Carib |          1987 |  (279)  |
| Missing Non Historical Results | BSD      | Carib |          1990 |  898    |
| Missing Non Historical Results | BSD      | Carib |          1987 |  18     |
| Missing Non Historical Results | BSD      | Carib |          1990 |  (50)   |
+--------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+
```

Comment: You can't. From your example data, there is no indication for why any record whether it should be labelled 1987 or 1990.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add another column to your `select` statement:

```
select [Data Type], [Currency], [Book Name], '1987' as Year, [1987] as Value
from [stage2$]
UNION ALL
select [Data Type], [Currency], [Book Name], '1990' as Year, [1990]
from [stage2$]
order by Year
```

Comment: I got a couple issues with this, `1987` and `1990` as `Year` still gives the same data in `Values`, However `"1987"` and `"1990"` with quotes seems to give the correct results, but now I need to order them one after the other, not all `1987` then all `1990`

Comment: @excelguy You can `order by` any field you need, just change the last line.  Quick note, without an `order by` clause, you cannot guarantee the order of the results.

Comment: Im not sure I am understanding. I want to order like so, `1987`, then `1990` , then `1987` then `1990`, alternating values in `Year`